# Save variables in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using a script query and script filter in my Elasticsearch query, as you can see below. Is it possible to save the calculated value of the query script and use it for sorting, so I don't have to calculate the same value again? Thank you.

```
    "sort" : {
        "_script" : { 
            "script" : "sqrt(pow((doc[l].value - l_value),2)+pow((doc[a].value - a_value),2)+pow((doc[b].value - b_value),2))",
            "type" : "number",
            "params" : {
                "l_value" : '10',
                "a_value" : '20',
                "b_value" : '20'
            },
            "order" : "asc"
        }
    },
    "query" : {
        "filtered" : {
            "filter" : {
                "script" : {
                    "script" : "sqrt(pow((doc[l].value - l_value),2)+pow((doc[a].value - a_value),2)+pow((doc[b].value - b_value),2)) < 20",
                    "params" : {
                        "l_value" : 10,
                        "a_value" : 20',
                        "b_value" : 20.'
                    }
                }
            },
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you have a look at ```script_fields``` like it's described in the docs: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/script-fields.html ?